# Как загрузить изображения из приложения на sdcard

Tags: android

Добрый день друзья
Возникла проблема в следующем, собственно есть приложение на андроиде
в нем в папке /res/drawable хранятся изображения 
эти изображения выводятся на linearlayout в качестве background'a 
так вот.
нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки картинка которая сейчас на экране в качестве background'a сохранялась допустим в папку /mnt/sdcard/myimgfolder. 
Если есть у кого нибудь какие нибудь мысли по этому поводу, буду благодарен

З.ы. забугорные сайты предлагают кое какие решения, но они не годятся, там предлагают выбирать картинку из стандартной галереи и сохранять ее sdcard ( зачем - нипонятно :) ). Я новичок в разработке под андроид так что не пинайте сильно. заранее спс

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых вам понадобится дополнительное разрешение (permission):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Во-вторых, чтобы узнать корень этой папки воспользуйтесь функцией:

```
File extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Answer (score 2):

Тянешь drawable с LinearLayout .

```
 myDrawable = myLinear.getBackground();
```

Конвертируешь в bitmap

```
Bitmap myImage= ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

//это с текущего linearLayout(или что там у тебя), если с res/drawable  то

```
Bitmap myImage= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.imageres);
```

и сохраняешь его

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, "image.jpg");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

всё найдено на забугорном сайте. В манифест добавить то, что указал ранее Dex

Comment: Делать сразу в лоб сохранение - плохая идея. Сперва вы используете

    File extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

чтобы узнать доступна ли директория для записи, а потом уже начинаете сохранять.

Comment: ну я думаю проверить на доступность sdcard, а потом записывать, хотя проверить на запись тоже не мешало бы, спс за совет

Comment: @dex , сделать проверку на сд карту это минута дела.. не думаю что у человека будут проблемы с этим

Comment: Что то оно не работает, нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит, не могли бы вы дать ссылку откуда взят код или показать весь код

Comment: @alogin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021728/android-writing-bitmap-to-sdcard вот к примеру.. в гугле задать save bitmap to sdcard android java и вы найдете еще больше примеров

Comment: спасибо, разобрался :)